# How do I get a map of a javascript array but do something different for last element?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, reactjs, jsx

What is the most elegant way to get a map of this array but do something different on the last array indexed item?

```
<div className="breadcrumb navigation">
   {
      folders.map(
         x => ([
            <a>{x}</a>,
            <i className="breadcrumb divider"></i>,
         ])
      )
   }
</div>
```

My issue is that the breadcrumb divider shouldn't be present at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map will give you the index:

```
folders.map((x, i) => ([
    <a>{x}</a>,
    i < (folders.length-1) ? <i className="breadcrumb divider"></i> : '',
])
```

Sorry for my lack of reactjs syntax.  Might be a bit off.

Also, this is true for all of the similar array functions (map, reduce, filter, etc)

Answer (score 2):

[`.map()` callback can take three arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), item, index and array. You can use these to check if it's the last item:

```
<div className="breadcrumb navigation">
   {
      folders.map((x, i, arr) => {

         // check if it's the last item
         if(i === arr.length - 1) {
             return <a>{x}</a>
         }

         return [
            <a>{x}</a>,
            <i className="breadcrumb divider"></i>,
         ];
      })
   }
</div>
```